# Systematic approach to find base of vectorspace given its elements' traits

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finitely-generated

I'm trying to find a base for a vector space that's given as a set with certain traits. Take this example:

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with
$$ V := \left\{ (a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : a + 3b + 2d = 0, 2a + b +c = 0 \right\} $$
and regular vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Obviously, the constraint is that the given equation system is fulfilled:
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{matrix}
$$

When solved, that means
$$
a = \frac{2\lambda - 3\mu}{5},\quad b= -\frac{4\lambda - \mu}{5},\quad c=\mu,\quad d = \lambda,\quad \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Of course, I could determine a few random vectors based on that constraint, *hope* that they'll form a generator and determine a basis based on that. But I imagine it would  only make proving that the base is indeed a base harder than necessary.

There must be a better, more straightforward way, isn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't take *random* vactors. Take the vector that corresponds to $\mu=1$ and $\lambda=0$ (you will get $\left(-\frac45,\frac15,1,0\right)$) and the one that corresponds to $\mu=0$ and $\lambda=1$. Then you will get two vectors which are necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: I see. We are basing that linear independence solely on the fact that for two vectors $v_1, v_2$ if e.g. $c_1 = 0$ and $c_2 \neq 0$, there'll never be a linear combination of $v_1$ that equals $v_2$; same for $d$. And now to prove that it actually is a basis, we just need to show that there is no $v_3$ such that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ linearly independent (since all bases have exactly $\dim(V)$ many vectors)?

Comment: They form a basis because it is a consequence of your computations that every vector from $V$ is a linear combination of the two vectors that I mentioned.